# Can't send the body of my Post request to my mongoDb database, using mongoos

Tags: express, mongoose, backend

I'm using Node and express for my backend request.
I'm trying to create a new member, the HTTP request goes through and I can see the Id in my database but the body does not show up! here is the code:

```
async function createMember(membersData) {
    let newMember = new Members(membersData)
    console.log("this is a new member", newMember)
    let createdMember = await newMember.save()
    console.log("saving members info", createdMember)
    return createdMember.id;
}

//route

router.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
    let newMember = req.body
    let createdId = await membersListModel.createMember(newMember)
    res.send(createdId)
    console.log("from API this is a new member", createdId)
})
```

Comment: ` body does not show up` what does it mean ? the body is your request body or saved data. body

Comment: save data. This is the mongoose schema, I receive an Id in the database but no first/last name!

const Members = mongoose.model('Members', {
    firstName: {
        type: String,
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String
    }
})